# SOSL query on ContentDocument

Tags: sosl, contentversion, files, dynamic-sosl

I have a requirement to search within files. To get that working, I have a SOSL query on `ContentVersion`. It seemed to work as expected when I tested as myself, however...

1. I myself seem to get the correct result, but other users receive search results that do not contain the search query. How is this possible and how can I fix it?
2. Is it normal that different users receive different results (excluding sharing rules of course)?
3. Is there any documentation for what I should and should not expect?